# Is it easy to toggle the vim plugin if you want to disable it?

Tags: vim, intellij-idea

I really want to use the vim plugin but before I install it I just want to know how easy it is to toggle it on/off?

Does it mess up any of the key bindings or when I toggle it on/off it will revert things nicely without issue?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's very easy to toggle the Vim plugin on or off. There will be an option under the Tools menu that will allow you to do so. Your previous keybindings shouldn't be affected if you decide to turn the Vim emulator off.

[image: vim emulator]

Comment: it really slowed my IDE down.

Comment: Hm, I haven't had any performance issues myself. You can try to see if there is an open problem in the [issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/VIM).

Comment: @coolbreeze any plugin slows the IDE down. the ideavim dragged me from Eclipse to IDEA. I 've started using eclipse since v2.0. Now if no ideavim, I won't start the intellij at all.  ^_^

Comment: This shortcut does not work. Neither have other shortcuts I have assigned to toggling VIM mode.  And vim mode does not allow me to use column mode editing. This is becoming a serious issue with ideaVIM

Answer (score 8):

Old post, but I was still looking for the answer, so here goes. Not enough rep to comment on the accepted answer, so I will expand on it here. It would appear that my IntelliJ did not have shortcut defined by default (maybe this has changed through the years). You must go into your settings and define a keyboard shortcut.

[IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3.3]
**Settings** -> **Keymap** -> **Plugins** -> **IdeaVim**. There should be a **Vim Emulator** option (which corresponds to the Tools menu option pictured above). Right-click on that item and select **Add Keyboard Shortcut**. Make the shortcut whatever you like...as long as it is not already assigned.

The shortcut keys will be reflected in the Tools menu if you later forget what you assigned.

Comment: This answer is really helpful, as the place from which the necessary keyboard shortcut has to be set is kind of hidden (4 menu levels!). NB: In my current install the menu option is called "Vim", rather than "Vim Emulator", and Alt-V seems to be a good choice of key for it.